# soap api v1 way to request customer_adress.list for all customers who updated after xxx date

Tags: api

Is there a way to retrieve the entire list of adresses that have changed after a given datetime?
It now fails because it wishes an user id.
I'd hate have to loop through all the adresses(which are more than 100.000 eventually....)

```
$this->mage->call('customer_address.list',
     array(
       array(
            'updated_at' => array('from' => '2009-06-10')
            )
          )
      );
```

and this is the error that is produced

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [101] Customer not exists. in public_html/config/core/magento.php:277 Stack trace:
#0 public_html/config/core/magento.php(277): SoapClient->__call('call', Array)
#1 public_html/config/core/magento.php(277): SoapClient->call('564bdd334d7eab1...', 'customer_addres...', Array)
#2 public_html/modules/magento/controllers/ajax.php(44): MagentoConnect->call('customer_addres...', Array)
#3 [internal function]: ajax->getNewAndChangeCustomers()
#4 public_html/index.php(30): call_user_func(Array)
#5 {main}   thrown in public_html/config/core/magento.php on line 277
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is native functionality for the `customer_address` entity. In other words, Magento expects address entries to be retrieved "per customer" (unfortunately). This can be seen in `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Api::items()`:

```
public function items($customerId)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->load($customerId);
    /* @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */

    if (!$customer->getId()) {
        $this->_fault('customer_not_exists');
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, [the API is extendable](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html), allowing you to roll your own implementation which you could use to augment and provide the very simple filter which you want.